# Simple HTTPS code

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Hi I'm trying to recieve a message via curl into wso2 esb on port 9090 (which is set up in axis2.xml) using the following code

```
`<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="att2" transports="https"        
 statistics="enable" trace="enable" startOnLoad="true">  
 <target faultSequence="fileWriteSequence" endpoint="conf:/users">
  <outSequence>
     <send />
  </outSequence>
</target>
<parameter name="enableMTOM">false</parameter>
</proxy>'
```

the curl command i'm using is: `curl -d this is a test" http://localhost:9090`

I dont see the file coming through on my stats and the response back from the curl command is "Empty reply from server"
any ideas?